# iOS 12 Swift save TrueDepth data to video

Tags: ios, swift, quicktime, avcapturemoviefileoutput, truedepth-camera

I've been trying to write TrueDepth data as a quicktime movie. I have examined the example from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera
I understand that it is possible to use [AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemoviefileoutput) to output a quicktime movie, but I have no idea how to implement this. I have been trying to do something simple to start with such as just saving a capture session from the front facing camera to a quicktime. Any help would appreciated. This is what I have so far:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var videoCaptureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    var input: AnyObject?

    var movieOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInTrueDepthCamera,
                                for: .video, position: .front)

        do {
            input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice!)
        } catch {
            print("video device error")
        }


        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.addInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)

        captureSession?.addOutput(movieOutput)

        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = previewView.layer.bounds
        previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
        captureSession?.startRunning()

    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us where the code stops, errors, etc?

Comment: this code works it doesn't fail, I just need to know how to add the functionality to  output a quicktime movie can be saved on the device